# Geometric properties of this particular torus $(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+P^2}-R)^2+Q^2z^2=r^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I've taken the liberty of boxing each answer. For the non-obvious answers I've shown how I arrived at my answers.

Take note that I've used the following definition in order to make my expressions shorter:
$$R'=R+r\cos{u}$$

---

[A visualization of the surface](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/rzyaxugn)

This particular torus differs from an ordinary torus only by the shape of the closed loop that rotates around the $z$-axis to generate the surface.

The surface is the collection of points in $ℝ^3$ satisfying

$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+P^2}-R)^2+Q^2z^2=r^2$$

Or, in cylindrical coordinates: $$(\sqrt{{\rho}^2+P^2}-R)^2+Q^2z^2=r^2$$

where

- $P,Q$ $\in$ $ℝ$
- $R,r$ $\in$ $(0,\infty)$
- $r<R$
- $|P|<R-r$

Let's use the following parametrization, where $\theta,u$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$

$$x=\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^{2}}\cos \theta$$

$$y=\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^{2}}\sin \theta$$

$$z=\frac{r}{Q}\sin u$$

1. Derive a closed-form expression for the Gaussian curvature in terms of $\theta$ and $u$ at an arbitrary point on the surface.
2. Derive a closed-form expression for the mean curvature in terms of $\theta$ and $u$ at an arbitrary point on the surface.
3. Along what curve and in what plane is the magnitude of the Gaussian curvature highest? (The curve should be a circle in some plane parallel to the plane $z=0$)
4. Along what curve and in what plane is the value of the Gaussian curvature the highest?
   (The curve should be a circle in some plane parallel to the plane $z=0$)
5. Consider the curve which is the answer to question 3. What is the Gaussian curvature of the surface at an arbitrary point on this curve? (The Gaussian curvature of the surface is the same at all points on this curve)
6. Consider the curve which is the answer to question 4. What is the Gaussian curvature of the surface at an arbitrary point on this curve? (The Gaussian curvature of the surface is the same at all points on this curve)
7. Consider the closed loop $$\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$$What is the area enclosed by this loop?
8. Consider the closed loop $$\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$$What is the perimeter of this loop?
9. What is the volume enclosed by the torus?
10. What is the surface area of the torus?
11. Consider the closed loop $$\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$$ What are the conditions necessary for the curvature at $t=\pi/2$ to be greater than the curvature at $t=0$?

---

**Questions 1 and 2** can be approached in the following way:

Let $R'=R+r\cos{u}$

The inverse metric is

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{(R')^2-P^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{Q^{2}\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)}{r^{2}\left(\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\right)} \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Let the matrix $A$ be the matrix corresponding to the second fundamental form

Then
$$A_{11}=\frac{(P^2-(R')^2)\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}}$$

$$A_{12}=A_{21}=0$$

$$A_{22}=\frac{-P^{2}r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\cos\left(u\right)-r\left(R'\right)\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)}{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}}$$

The product of the inverse metric and the second fundamental form (with the inverse metric on the left) is our shape operator

Let the matrix $B$ be the shape operator

Then

$$B_{11}=\frac{-\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}}$$

$$B_{12}=B_{21}=0$$

$$B_{22}=\frac{-Q^{2}\left(P^{2}r\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\cos\left(u\right)+\left(R'\right)\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\right)}{r\left(\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

The determinant of $B$ gives us the Gaussian curvature

Thus, a closed-form expression for the Gaussian curvature in terms of $\theta$ and $u$ is:

$$\boxed{\frac{Q^{2}\left(P^{2}r\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\cos\left(u\right)+\left(R'\right)\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\right)\cos(u)}{r\left(\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\right)^{2}}}$$

The mean curvature is just half the trace of B.

Thus, a closed-form expression for the mean curvature in terms of $\theta$ and $u$ is:

$$\boxed{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}}+\frac{Q^{2}\left(P^{2}r\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\cos\left(u\right)+\left(R'\right)\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\right)}{r\left(\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}})}$$

---

**Question 3** is rather easy and the answer is straightforward.

The curve is the circle $$\boxed{(\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}\cos t,\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}\sin t,0)}$$ and the plane which this circle is in is the plane $\boxed{z=0}$

---

**Question 4** is rather easy and the answer is straightforward

We know that along the circle $$(\sqrt{(R^2-P^{2}}\cos \theta,\sqrt{(R^2-P^{2}}\sin \theta, \frac{r}{Q})$$ the Gaussian curvature is zero and we know that there are points on the torus with positive Gaussian curvature, so we can deduce that the circle $(\sqrt{(R^2-P^{2}}\cos \theta,\sqrt{(R^2-P^{2}}\sin \theta, \frac{r}{Q})$ is not the curve we are looking for.

We also know that the circle along which the Gaussian curvature is greatest must reside on the portion of the torus which has positive curvature.

$u=-\pi/2$ corresponds to a circle along which the torus has zero Gaussian curvature.

$u=0$ corresponds to a circle along which the torus has positive Gaussian curvature.

$u=\pi/2$ corresponds to a circle along which the torus has zero Gaussian curvature.

By symmetry (the surface is the same on either side of the plane $z=0$), we can then reason that the highest Gaussian curvature occurs along the circle corresponding to $u=0$

Thus, the answer to question 4 is that the curve along which the value of the Gaussian curvature is the highest is the circle

$$\boxed{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}\cos t,\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}\sin t,0)}$$ and the plane which this curve is in is the plane $\boxed{z=0}$

---

**Questions 5 and 6** can be approached in the following way:

Given that the Gaussian curvature is the product of the principal curvatures, we can reduce the number of dimensions we're working in by observing that the surface has an infinite order of rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis

Consider the cross section composed of two disjoint loops created by slicing the surface with a plane containing the $z$-axis.

As a first order of business we can concern ourselves with finding the curvature of one of these loops at the point where the curvature is greatest

Parametrize one of the loops in our cross section with the following:

$$f(t)=\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$$

Using $$\kappa=±\frac{x'y''-y'x''}{\left(\left(x'\right)^{2}+\left(y'\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

we get

$$\kappa=\frac{r^{2}\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)\left(\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)+P^{2}r^{3}\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)}{|Q|\left(\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}}+\frac{r^{2}}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(t\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

To answer question 5 we need only find the curvature of the closed loop
$f(t)=\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$ at $t=\pi$

Plugging $\pi$ into our expression for the curvature we find that the curvature at $t=\pi$ is

$$\frac{Q^{2}\left(R-r\right)}{r\sqrt{\left(R-r\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}$$

This means we've now obtained one of the principal curvatures up to a minus sign. The other principal curvature is just the curvature of the circle $$\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}\cos t,\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}\sin t,0)$$
which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}}$$

The Gaussian curvature of our torus is obviously negative along this circle, so we need to be sure to include a minus sign when taking the product of the principal curvatures

Thus, the answer to question 5 is that the Gaussian curvature at an arbitrary point along this circle is

$$\boxed{\frac{Q^{2}\left(r-R\right)}{r\left(R-r\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}$$

To answer question 6 we need only find the curvature of the closed loop
$f(t)=\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$ at $t=0$

Plugging $0$ into our expression for the curvature we find that the curvature at $t=0$ is

$$\frac{Q^{2}\left(R+r\right)}{r\sqrt{\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}$$

This means we've now obtained one of the principal curvatures up to a minus sign. The other principal curvature is just the curvature of the circle $$\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}\cos t,\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}\sin t,0)$$
which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}}$$

Thus, the answer to question 6 is that the Gaussian curvature at an arbitrary point along this circle is

$$\boxed{\frac{Q^{2}\left(R+r\right)}{r\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}$$

---

**Question 7** can be approached in the following way:

Using
$$f(t)=\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$$
we can switch to rectangular coordinates and get
$$\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-R\right)^{2}+Q^{2}y^{2}=r^{2}$$

Solving for $y$ we get

$$y=±\frac{1}{Q}\sqrt{r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}}$$

Next we need to find the zeros of
$$r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}$$

Since we defined $P$,$R$, and $r$ in such a way that $r<R$ and $|P|<R-r$ there are going to be zeros that do not apply to our situation

From these zeros we can obtain the upper and lower bounds in $x$ for the integral we shall use.

The two solutions to $$r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}=0$$ that we care about are $x=\sqrt{r^{2}+R^{2}-2rR-P^{2}}$ and $x=\sqrt{r^{2}+R^{2}+2rR-P^{2}}$

This gives us our lower and upper bounds for the area integral.

Thus, one possible answer to question 7 is that the area enclosed by the loop is

$$\boxed{\frac{2}{\left|Q\right|}\int_{\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}}^{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}}\sqrt{r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}}dx}$$

---

**Question 8** can be answered very straightforwardly

The perimeter of the closed loop is
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{2\pi}r\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{r}{2}\sin\left(2t\right)+R\sin\left(t\right)\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(t\right)\left(\left(r\cos\left(t\right)+R\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)}{\left(r\cos\left(t\right)+R\right)^{2}-p^{2}}}dt}$$

---

**Question 9** is straightforward because the surface has an infinite order of rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis

To compute the volume of the torus we can use the answer to question 7, which is the area of the closed loop $f(t)=\left(\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}},\frac{r}{Q}\sin t\right)$

The answer to question 9 is that the volume of the torus is

$$\boxed{\frac{4\pi{r}}{\left|Q\right|}\int_{\sqrt{(R-r)^2-p^{2}}}^{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-p^{2}}}\sqrt{r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}}dx}$$

---

**Question 10** can be approached in the following way:

All we need is to derive the surface element from the partial derivatives.

Let $$S(\theta,u)=(\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^2}\cos\theta,\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^2}\sin\theta,\frac{r}{Q}\sin{u})$$

Then $$S_\theta=(-\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^2}\sin\theta,\sqrt{(R+r\cos{u})^2-P^2}\cos\theta,0)$$

$$S_u=(-\frac{r\sin\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos\left(u\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(u\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}\cos\theta,-\frac{r\sin\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos\left(u\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\left(R+r\cos\left(u\right)\right)^{2}-P^{2}}}\sin\theta,\frac{r}{Q}\cos(u))$$

$$|S_{\theta}\times S_u|=\sqrt{\frac{r^{2}}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(u\right)\left(\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)+r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}}$$

So we have the surface integral

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{r^{2}}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(u\right)\left(\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)+r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}}d{\theta}du$$

which can be simplified to

$$2\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{r^{2}}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(u\right)\left(\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)+r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}}du$$

And thus, if we're fine with having an answer to question 10 that is expressed as a definite integral, then  the surface area of the torus is
$$\boxed{2\pi{r}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1}{Q^{2}}\cos^{2}\left(u\right)\left(\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)+\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\left(R+r\cos u\right)^{2}}du}$$

---

**Question 11** can be approached in the following way:

We want to know whether the curvature is greater at $t=0$ or at $t=\pi/2$

At $t=0$ the curvature is $$\frac{Q^{2}\left(R+r\right)\left(\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)}{r\left(\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ $\tag1$

At $t=\pi/2$ the curvature is $$\frac{R^{2}-P^{2}}{\left|Q\right|R^{2}r}$$ $\tag2$

Setting (2) to be grater than (1) we get the following inequality:

$$\frac{R^{2}-P^{2}}{\left|Q\right|R^{2}r}>\frac{Q^{2}\left(R+r\right)\left(\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)}{r\left(\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Now all that's left to do in order to arrive at the answer is to simplify this inequality

Thus, the curvature at $t=\pi/2$ will be greater than the curvature at $t=0$ if and only if:

$$\boxed{\left|Q\right|^{3}R^{2}\left(R+r\right)+\left(P^{2}-R^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(R+r\right)^{2}-P^{2}}<0}$$

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\theta,z)$ the equation describing the torus becomes a bit simpler:
$$
(\sqrt{\color{red}{\rho}^2+P^2}-R)^2+Q^2z^2=r^2
$$
(I capitalized your $p,q$ so that $\rho$ is easier to distinguish from $P$). It is now clear (I am sure you knew that but it helps to tell this your readers) that this particular torus differs from an ordinary torus only by the elliptic shape of the curves that rotate around the $z$-axis. Can you figure out if your other equations also become simpler in this parametization?

Comment: @KurtG. is it the case that since the Gaussian curvature is just the product of principal curvatures then we can reduce the problem down to considering only the egg-shaped cross-section curves and their curvatures? It seems to me that for questions 3,4,5 and 6 we don't have to deal with a surface at all but rather with one of these egg-shaped curves. As far as questions 1 and 2 are concerned, I need to derive the shape operator given some particular parametrization of the surface. I think the parametrization I choose is a pretty natural one to choose

Comment: If an ellipse can nowadays be an "egg" why not a hen as well? Jokes aside. I'd prefer mathematical language. I do not know the solution to your problem. You seem versed enough to try a parametrization that I believe could be simpler. Of course you don't have to do that.

Comment: @KurtG. Is it still accurate to describe the curve as an ellipse even though it doesn't have all of the same rotational symmetries that an ellipse has? In my mind, it looks a lot more like an egg than an ellipse because it has a "top" with a greater curvature than the "bottom". If the term 'ellliptic' still applies then that's news to me but I'm glad I learned about this usage of the term.

Comment: Seems right when I think about it. When $P$ is zero it should be an ellipse. Otherwise an "egg". I don't have Desmos here at the moment so cannot verify. Anyway: the cylindrical coordinates are not quite dead yet I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. Since there is a confusion about $P$, I took $P=0$. Let $Q=1$. $Q\neq 1$ can be handled similarly.

Q1.

The position vector is
$$\mathbf{x}=\langle R'cos\theta,R'\sin\theta,r\sin u\rangle$$
where $R'=R+r\cos u$. Then
$$\mathbf{x}_\theta=\langle -R'sin\theta,R'\cos\theta,0\rangle$$
$$\mathbf{x}_u=\langle -r\sin u \cos\theta,-r\sin u\sin\theta,r\cos u\rangle$$
and the unit normal vector field is
$$\mathbf{N}=\langle \cos u\cos\theta,\cos u\sin\theta,\sin u\rangle.$$
The [Weingarten equations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeingartenEquations.html) are
$$S(\mathbf{x}_\theta)=-\mathbf{N}_\theta=-\frac{\cos u}{R'}\mathbf{x}_\theta+0.\mathbf{x}_u$$
$$S(\mathbf{x}_u)=-\mathbf{N}_u=0.\mathbf{x}_\theta
-\frac1{r}\mathbf{x}_u$$
where $S$ is the shape operator. Hence the principal curvatures are $\kappa_1=-\frac{\cos u}{R'}$ and $\kappa_2=-\frac1r$. The Gaussian curvature is $\kappa=\kappa_1\kappa_2=\frac{\cos u}{rR'}$.

Q7.

By Green's theorem, the area of a loop is $A=\int_Cxdy$. For the loop $\langle\sqrt{(R+r\cos t)^2-P^2},\frac rQ\cos t\rangle$ we have
$$A=\frac{2r}{Q}\int_0^\pi 
\sqrt{(R+r\cos t)^2-P^2}
\cos t\, dt$$
which is impossible integral.

Comment: If we take the special case where $P=0$ and $Q=1$ and we abide by the restriction that $R>r$ then doesn't that mean we simply have an ordinary ring torus? (The classic quintessential torus, with nothing modified). Assuming that what you've described is an ordinary ring torus, it looks to me that your principal curvatures are correct, and your answer for the Gaussian curvature is correct as well.

Comment: I've attempted to clear up the confusion about $P$ by providing an imposed restriction on $P$, namely that $|P|<R-r$ (I've also specified that $R$ and $r$ are necessarily positive). If there is still confusion about $P$ please elaborate; I want to make my setup of the problem entirely issue-free.

Comment: In the general case $\kappa_1=\frac{-\cos\left(u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}}$
and $\kappa_2=\frac{-Q^{2}\left(P^{2}r\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\cos\left(u\right)+\left(R'\right)\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\right)}{r\left(\left(\left(R'\right)^{2}-P^{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(u\right)+Q^{2}\left(R'\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\left(u\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.
If we plug in $Q=1$ and $P=0$ then these simplify to your $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$. This gives me confidence in my answers to questions 1 and 2

Comment: @SimonM Omg. You put so much in this question. Are you doing Muster of Science or something like that?

Comment: The reason there are so many parts to this question is that for my own curiosity I wanted to give a comprehensive geometric description of this torus. If I think of more questions I may add them on eventually and attempt to answer them. For now, I've managed to answer the first 11 questions

Comment: One thing to be careful about with question 7: $Q$ can be negative, so to compensate for that we can write $A=\frac{2r}{|Q|}\int_0^\pi 
\sqrt{(R+r\cos t)^2-P^2}\cos t\, dt$ I do think your answer is probably equivalent to the answer I came up with, which is $A=\frac{2}{\left|Q\right|}\int_{\sqrt{(R-r)^2-P^{2}}}^{\sqrt{(R+r)^2-P^{2}}}\sqrt{r^{2}+2R\sqrt{x^{2}+P^{2}}-x^{2}-P^{2}-R^{2}}dx$

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

- By shifting the rulers in your GeoGebra app it is easy to see that this surface
  is not always a torus. Problems occur for large $P\,.$
- When we set for simplicity $Q=1$ it is easy to see that only for certain $P$
  there is a $z$ that solves the equation
  $$\tag{1}
  (\sqrt{\rho^2+P^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2\,
  $$
  since this implies
  \begin{align}\tag{2}
  (\sqrt{\rho^2+P^2}-R)^2&\ge r^2\\
  -r\le \sqrt{\rho^2+P^2}-R&\le r\tag{3}
  \end{align}
  \begin{align}\tag{4}
  -r+R\le \sqrt{\rho^2+P^2}\le r+R\\[2mm] 
  (R-r)^2\le\rho^2+P^2\le (R+r)^2\tag{5}\,.
  \end{align}
  In particular we must have $|P|\le R+r\,.$

This makes me think that you should change the defining equation to
$$\tag{1'}
(\sqrt{\rho^2\color{red}{-}P^2}-R)^2+Q^2z^2=r^2\,
$$
and start over again.

Last not least: where does that problem come from?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150046/discussion-on-answer-by-kurt-g-geometric-properties-of-this-particular-torus); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.